# npm install with other directory using one "package.json"

Tags: npm, npm-install

hello i want to install 2 `node_modules` (other directory) only one command.

```
| - folderOne
  | - node_modules
  | - package.json // current directory
|
| - folderTwo
  | - node_modules
```

for example.

when i write `npm install` in `folderOne`, same `node_modules` installed with both `folderOne` and `folderTwo`

or

```
| - folderOne
  | - node_modules
  | - package.json // current directory
|
| - folderTwo
  | - node_modules
  | - package.json // automatic installed
```

i want to write `npm install` in `folderOne`, `npm install` excute in `folderTwo`

how do that??